# How to custom the LayerSwitcher in OpenLayers to toggle all layers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to have a checkbox in my layer switcher "turn all layers on/off".
how can I do that ?

I thought about adding an empty layer with that name and somehow bind her an event "On Show" and "On Hide" to toggle the rest of the layers.

Any better solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I did this in code using check boxes in a  that called a function. All the function did was to iterate through all the Layers and just make the visible or invisible.

For Example:

```
function layersOnOff(toggle){
    var LayerList = map.layers;
    for(var a = 0; a < LayerList.length; a++ ){
        LayerList[a].visibility = toggle;
    };
}
```

Cheers

Mark